# How to convert Java object to Json object and put in json array

Tags: java, json, ajax, servlets, web-deployment

I want to do a ajax call on a button click. This will fetch records from mysql and will put in employee object. Now i want to send the employee object array kind of thing back to my ajax call. So thought of using JSON.
package com;This code is working fine but i am unable to use Employee class and its object.Here i directly used JSON and its working.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class SelectUsers {
    public JSONArray selectQueryDemo() throws SQLException
    {
        GlobalConnection gc=new GlobalConnection();
        Connection conn=gc.getConnection();
        Statement s=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result=s.executeQuery("select * from tblemployees");
        String name = "";
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        while(result.next())
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("id", result.getInt(1));
                obj.put("name", result.getString(2));
                obj.put("gender", result.getString(3));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/